# Eigenvalue eigenvector (basis)

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question regarding the use of eigenvectors as basis vectors.

For A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -4 &7\\-4 & 4 & -4\\7& -4 & 1 \end{bmatrix}

"By expressing an arbitrary vector $r$ in terms of the eigenvectors or otherwise, show
that a non-zero vector $e$ exists such that
$Ar \cdot e = 0$
for all $r$."

I am not sure how I should tackle the question. I started off trying to convert $Ar$ into a diagonalized matrix. Is this the correct approach?

Thank you

Comment: There must be something you are leaving out, probably something about $A$, as the question as posed makes no sense. If $A$ is singular, for example, then $Ar$ lies in a proper subspace, so there's a non-zero $e$ orthogonal to that subspace.

Comment: So sorry, you are right. I missed out in specifying A in the question. Thank you so much..

Comment: OK. Now, can you follow the steps I suggested?

Comment: Are you still there?

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial $p_A(X)=\det(A-XI_3)$ of your matrix is
$$
p_A(X)=72X+6X^2-X^3
$$
which has roots $-6$, $0$ and $12$.

So the matrix is diagonalizable, hence it has a basis consisting of eigenvectors. (The fact that it is diagonalizable also directly follows from the fact that $A$ is symmetric.)

Just find an eigenvector relative to each eigenvalue and you have found a basis as required.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as stated --

"By expressing an arbitrary vector r in terms of the eigenvectors or otherwise, show that a non-zero vector $e$ exists such that $Ar \cdot e=0$ for all $r$."

-- is false. For instance, if $A$ is the identity matrix, then there is no such vector $e$. I think that you have left off some important assumption about the matrix $A$.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right, I missed out in including the matrix A in the question, so there's a restriction present. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Say that your matrix $A$ has eigenvectors $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ (resp.). Then you can express an arbitrary vector $r$ as $r=c_1x_1+c_2x_2+c_3x_3$ in the basis $\left\{x_1,x_2,x_3\right\}$. Therefore:
$$Ar\cdot e=A(c_1x_1+c_2x_2+c_3x_3)\cdot e=(c_1Ax_1+c_2Ax_2+c_3Ax_3)\cdot e=(c_1\lambda_1x_1+c_2\lambda_2x_2+c_3\lambda_3x_3)\cdot e$$
What can you say about $e$ when $Ar\cdot e=0$?

Comment: can i say that e is a scalar multiple of any one of the 3 eigenvectors? say e = kx_1? So that when I perform the scalar product, I can eliminate the other 2 eigenvectors

Comment: @kane9530 That won't eliminate $x_1$ though; you'll have to find a linear combination of the three eigenvectors. But that's the idea, yes. Also note that you could simplify this equation by noticing that $\lambda_3=0$.